# Can open my iOS 1password db on my Windows7 desktop?

Tags: itunes, iphone, dropbox, 1password

I use 1password. On my iPhone. I dropped my iPhone. Screen is dead and can't use 1password. So I open up 1password on my windows7 machine. This is where I discover that apparently my 1password dropbox sync stopped synching some 6 months ago.

Is there any way that I can open the iOS7 1Password db that is backed up in iTunes using the desktop version of 1Password so I can get the last 6 months worth of passwords and re-sync with dropbox?

Comment: You might be able to.  It would involve finding a file explorer for iPhone.  Good luck with that Apple does everything in its power to prevent that.  In all likelyhood it won't work even if you did find the file.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this answer comes pretty late, but perhaps it will help others who land here. If you get another iOS device, you can [restore the 1Password backup on that iOS device](https://guides.agilebits.com/1password-ios/5/en/topic/itunes-backups).

That backup format is not currently compatible with the Windows version of 1Password, unfortunately. It is compatible with 1Password for Mac, however, so if you have a Mac and can download the free trial of 1Password for Mac, you can [restore the backup there](https://guides.agilebits.com/1password-mac/4/en/topic/restore-from-backup) and then [sync with Dropbox](https://guides.agilebits.com/1password-mac/4/en/topic/sync-with-dropbox).